# How to assign within apply family?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have data.frame that contains several factors and i want to rename factor levels for all of these factors. E.g.:

```
mydf <- data.frame(col1 = as.factor(c("A","A",NA,NA)),col2 = as.factor(c("A",NA,NA,"A")))
mydf <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydf,addNA))
```

Note that the real life example has way more than just two columns. Hence I would like to use apply to assign other level names to all of these columns, just like in:

```
levels(mydf$col1) <- c("1","0")
```

I tried the following but it did not work…

```
 apply(mydf,1,function(x) levels(x) <- c("1","0"))
```

I am not really surprised it doesn't work but I have no better ideas right now. Should I use `with` maybe?

EDIT: I realized I made a mistake here by oversimplifying things. I used `addNA` to account for the fact, that NAs should not handled as NAs anymore. Thus I also want to relabel them.
This doesn't work with Andrie's suggestion and returns the following error message:

```
 labels = c("1",  : invalid labels; length 2 should be 1 or 1
```

Note that I updated my example df.

Comment: You don't say what you want to do with the NA levels.  Rename them to what?

Comment: after using addNA I have levels 1 and <NA>. And I like to have the NA category renamed to 0 – just like they were ordinary factor levels and had never been NAs.

Comment: @Charles: what's wrong with the categorical tag? This is a serious question. Is it because it is so language agnostic? Using the R term for categorical ( `factor` ) would not have been better. Should I leave the whole aspect out and why?

Comment: @ran2, the issue isn't really with the term and this question as much as it is with how unfortunately generic the term is and how *other people* tend to misunderstand and mis-use generic-sounding tags.  Could you perhaps find another word, or a more specific phrase instead?  I'm going to wager we already have a tag for the thing you're trying to describe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change levels by reference using `setattr()` from packages [`bit`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit/index.html) or [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/). This avoids copying the whole dataset, and since you said you have a lot of columns ...

```
require(bit)          # Either package
require(data.table)   #
setattr(mydf[[1]],"levels",c("1","0"))
setattr(mydf[[2]],"levels",c("1","0"))
```

That can be done in a simple `for` loop which is very fast.  It is your responsibility to ensure that you replace the levels vector with a vector of the same length, otherwise the factor may no longer be valid. And, you have to replace the whole levels vector with this method. There is an internal way in `data.table` to replace particular level names by reference, but probably no need to go that far.

Comment: Why not `attr(mydf[[1]], "levels") <- c("1","0")` or `levels(mydf[[1]]) <- c("1","0")`?

Comment: @Joshua `tracemem(mydf)` first, see the 4 copies (of the _whole_ object). Keep `tracemem` on then try `setattr()`: no copies at all, none. Then give `mydf` 1 billion rows and watch the others fail with `out of memory`, when `setattr()` works fine (and quickly).

Comment: Ah, of course, because you're subsetting the data.frame.  My tests on a single vector didn't create copies.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: Your solution does work with lapply too, which I`d prefer. Any reason why you recommend the for loop here?
`lapply(mydf,setattr,name="levels",value=c("1","0"))`

Comment: @ran2 Interesting. As long as that `lapply` doesn't copy each vector of `mydf` and construct a new `data.frame`, then should be ok. `tracemem` won't show that though. With a `for` you know no copy is taking place but with the `lapply` there's some doubt. Use `.Internal(inspect(mydf))` to compare the pointer values in this case to see if a new objects has been created.